# How to remove CKEditor Button Properties context menu item

Tags: ckeditor

I have a plugin where I'm adding a button to the editor via insertHtml:

```
editor.insertHtml('<input type = "button" value = "my button" />');
```

When you right-click on the button, you are presented with a "Button Properties" option in the context menu.  I cannot figure out how to remove that item via removeMenuItem().  I am able to remove the Paste option from the menu via removeMenuItem('paste'), but removeMenuItem('Button Properties') does not work.  Anyone have any experience with this?

This is version 3.6.5